# Join with a groupby operation in SQL

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I am playing with W3Schools SQL environment. A pre-defined database is setup [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_left).

Tables to be used: Customer and Orders.

To get all the info from Customer we can do:

```
SELECT * FROM [Customers]
```

To get Customers who have only less than 3 orders we do:

```
SELECT CustomerID, count(*) as num_orders FROM [Orders] group by customerID having num_orders<3
```

To get the Customers we have in London, we do:

```
SELECT * FROM [Customers] where city="London"
```

> **Question:** How can I get, for every customer in London (with less than 3 orders), how many orders they have?

I know it has to be a Left join, as I want to keep all customers even if they have N/A orders (so, no records in "Orders"), but I am having a hard time to make it work.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM [Customers] where city="London"
left join (SELECT CustomerID, count(*) as num_orders FROM [Orders] group by customerID having num_orders<3) as data
on customers.CustomerID= data.CustomerID
```

But the environment gives no meaninful info about the error.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax is:

```
SELECT c.*, o.num_orders
FROM [Customers] c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT o.CustomerID, COUNT(*) as num_orders
      FROM [Orders] o
      GROUP BY o.customerID 
     ) o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE c.city = 'London';
```

Notes:

- The most important difference is the order of the clauses.  `WHERE` comes *after* the `FROM` clause.
- The `HAVING` clause is removed, because the question is for all customers in London.
- Single quotes are used to quote *London*.  Single quotes are the standard string delimiter.
- The query uses table aliases, and these are specifically chosen to be very short and related to the table names.
- All columns are qualified.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I wrote incorrectly the question, the having clause is indeed needed (I fixed the question), but I just added it after "Group by" and its working.

Comment: I want to have all the customers, but I want N/A if they have more than 2 orders, but maybe filtering after could be better. At the end, I just want 0,1 and 2 order customers, either with N/A if they have more than 2, or just not there.

Comment: @nxgtrturbo . . . Then just change the join to an inner join and put the having clause back in.